# how to get a UITextView to Clear like a UITextField does

Tags: uitextfield, uitextview

im trying to get a UITextView to Clear like a UITextField does cant seem to get this I making a app that need to clear after tapping send much like a email or tweet with several lines of text. any code would be great thanks so very much

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a button and then:

```
- (IBAction)clearField:(id)sender
{
    textView.text = @""; // textView is of type UITextView
}
```